# Is this type of ground wire connection NEC compliant?

Tags: electrical, nec

Found this recently, done by a licensed electrical company in the state of California.

[image: "Roll your own" wire nut]

Is this compliant? If not, is there anything that could be added to make it legal? (I see "ground clamps" for attaching wire to pipe that look as if they'd provide a mechanical connection.) Would you just parcel them out into appropriately sized wire nuts? The box is a 2 gang, and getting full, but it's in a crawlspace, so could get an extension if needed.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't already over the fill limit? I'm counting at least 10 whites, and I'm assuming there's 10 blacks blacks to go with it.  That's a *ton* of 12 gauge in a 2 gang box.

Comment: Agreed, it looks WAY overfilled. Although, not having devices (simply a junction box) lets you get away with more wires.

Comment: I'll get back under there and count wires/ note box volume to do a proper fill calc. It is just a junction box, and it *is* really well packed in there. The only slightly deceptive thing with respect to the total number of wires in there is that all the wires are on one circuit, with jumpers between the wire nuts (2 for white, 2 for black). Thanks for all the info.

Comment: That's old-school, he "served" that.  [link](http://www2.irm.org/blogs/archives/1356-Serving-spanwire,-part-1.html) That may be code legal for down guys, but I doubt it's legal for grounds.  I would install a second junction box right next to the first to ease fill and provide room for expansion.

Comment: @WolfHarper Would you agree that this should've been answered critically of who did it? Like, Call the Inspector, Report their License, Don't use that SINGLE circuit until it's done right, etc., etc., etc.!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply twisting is not enough. You need a mechanical connection as well. Wire nut, crimp, etc.

NEC

> **110.14 Electrical Connections**
>
> Because of different characteristics of dissimilar metals, devices
>   such as pressure terminal or pressure splicing connectors and
>   soldering lugs shall be identified for the material of the conductor
>   and shall be properly installed and used. Conductors of dissimilar
>   metals shall not be intermixed in a terminal or splicing connector
>   where physical contact occurs between dissimilar conductors (such as
>   copper and aluminum, copper and copper-clad aluminum, or aluminum and
>   copper-clad aluminum), unless the device is identified for the purpose
>   and conditions of use. Materials such as solder, fluxes, inhibitors,
>   and compounds, where employed, shall be suitable for the use and shall
>   be of a type that will not adversely affect the conductors,
>   installation, or equipment.
>
> **(B) Splices.**
>
> Conductors shall be spliced or joined with splicing devices identified
>   for the use or by brazing, welding, or soldering with a fusible metal
>   or alloy. Soldered splices shall first be spliced or joined so as to
>   be mechanically and electrically secure without solder and then be
>   soldered. All splices and joints and the free ends of conductors shall
>   be covered with an insulation equivalent to that of the conductors or
>   with an insulating device identified for the purpose.
>
> Wire connectors or splicing means installed on conductors for direct
>   burial shall be listed for such use.

Answer (score -1):

NEC codes
250.148 and 110.14(B)

That kind of locks it in that they should be covered by something. I've seen them without for less wires, but that's a lot of wires to rely on a good twist.